# LAN Web application with Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-applications, offline, multiplayer, lan

I would like to be able to create a **turn based web game** (such as a kind of Monopoly), in which people visit it via their smartphone or PC web browser and can connect all together into the *same session*.

It would be **like a LAN connection**, where one of them (on my personal point of view) would work as a server, letting users to get into their match, and the others would connect to it to be able to synchronise the game progress all together.

I don't want you to bring me the solution, but the technologies I should read about (such as websockets, etc.) and **if it's possible** - because it may be impossible to do with the actual web technology.

I would like it **to be purely in JS**, because **I'd love it to be an offline** web application and I should be able to **cache the files**.

**The steps** I've got on my mind (maybe it can help) would be:

1. All users go to http://www.gameurl.com
2. One of the users starts "party"
3. The other users "search for parties"
4. They find a party near them (LAN by WiFi, for example)
5. They enter into the party
6. They all are able to play by turns, seeing in real-time what the others do

As I told, I don't know even if it's possible but I've been searching for ways to do it and I haven't been able to get the right information so I can start to find new approaches and technologies.

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/). It established a direct connection between two users, so this solve your problem.

It is based on [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/).